# Java Upcasting Nested Type Parameter

Tags: java, java-6, type-parameter, upcasting

Given the Java code below, I want to know why upcasting `Foo<String>` to `Foo<object>` does not work? Essentially I want to tell Java that if `T` is a subclass of `S`, then `Foo<T>` is a subclass of `Foo<S>`. I know there is a way to do this in Scala but is there a way to do this in Java? If not, is there a workaround to get the below code to compile?

```
class Foo<T> {
    T t;
    public Foo(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }
}

class Main {
    public static Foo<object> getFoo() {
        Foo<String> foo = new Foo("foo");
        return foo; // this throws a compile time exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues,

1. `Foo(T obj) {`
2. `Foo<Object> foo....`

The below code works fine.

```
class Foo<T> {
    T obj;
    Foo(T obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }
}

class Main {
    public static Foo<Object> getFoo() {
        Foo<Object> foo = new Foo("foo");
        return foo;
    }
}
```